# $f^{-1}(f(E))=E$ implies $f$ is one-to-one

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose that, for a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$, it is given that the following is true:
$$f^{-1}(f(E))=E$$
(Where $E\subset X$).  How can I use this to prove that $f$ is one-to-one?  I'm really not sure how to set this up formally, as I have an intuitive understanding as to why but simply struggle to put it into proper mathematical notation.

Comment: Suppose a point had two preimages. Let  $E$ be the subset of $X$ consisting of precisely one of those points. Then see that the above is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Conider the subsets $E$ that has a single element. What implies that $f^{-1}(f(\{x\}))=\{x\}$ for every $x\in X$?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose not.  Then $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=\bar y $ for some $\bar y \in Y$, and $x_1\not = x_2$...

Let $E=\{x_1\}$.  Then $x_2\in f^{-1}(f(E))$...  Thus $f^{-1}(f(E))\supsetneq E$, a contradiction ...